# How to avoid waiting for a thread to finish execution - Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I have the following structure defined in Python -

[image]

There are two threads. Each thread scans the branch vertically downwards and prints its value. On reaching the end of that branch, it moves a step ahead along the horizontal axis. Like, Thread1 will print a1, a2 and a3. At the same time, Thread 2 will scan b1. When both the thread finish execution, Thread 1 will jump to block B and Thread 2 will jump to block C to carry out the same process.

When all the blocks are done, the process starts again from the beginning. I have written a script for the same -

```
def printTags(DevObj):
    if DevObj == None:
        return -1
    TagObj = DevObj.tagPointer
    while TagObj != None:
        time.sleep(5)
        print TagObj.id
        TagObj = TagObj.nextTag

import threading, thread

# temp1 points to Block A.
# temp2 points to Block B.

while True:
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=printTags, args=(temp1,))
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=printTags, args=(temp2,))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()

    if temp1.nextDevice != None:
        temp1 = temp1.nextDevice
    else:
        temp1 = start.nextDevice

    if temp2.nextDevice != None:
        temp2 = temp2.nextDevice
    else:
        temp2 = start.nextDevice
```

However, you can see that when the threads are working on block A and B, Thread 1 will take more time than Thread 2 as it has to print more values. Because of this, Thread 2 remains unused for some time. I want to avoid this idle time. How can I do so?

Comment: There are many options. How would you want it to behave? For instance, you could have the `while True` loop within the thread, so a thread does not finish. Instead, it continues with the next device. Or you can remove the `join` and have some other logic from *outside*.

Comment: I will try out the first option. I did try by removing join() but the output didnt follow any order. It would be helpful if you could tell me what could be the logic for that

Comment: I added `while True` loop inside the thread and it is giving me what I want. But is it safe to run an infinite loop inside a thread? They are supposed to be used for light weight tasks only. I need this thread to run for a long time. Will the thread be able to handle it?

Comment: I don't get it. You say `Because of this, Thread 2 remains unused for some time. I want to avoid this idle time.` but before you say `When both the thread finish execution,...` so I understand that you want to wait for both threads to finish before continuing. So what do you want, for both of them to wait for each other or not?

Comment: Both the threads wait for each other to finish execution. I don;t want that. If one thread finishes its part it should move on to the next block immediately.

Comment: There is no ptoblem with a thread running for a long time. On the other hand, you probably want to be able to stop it at some time. Consider making [`daemon`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon) threads, if you don't care how they are killed. Or you may implement some way of stopping them gracefully (e.g. a `stop` flag)...

Comment: For what it's worth, consider `DevObj is None` and `while TagObj is not None`.  PEP 8 recommends that ["\[c\]omparisons to singletons like None should always be done with is or is not , never the equality operators."](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id42)

Answer (score 1):

There are different approaches you can take, but I would like to point out two of them:

First, use Semaphore, this one as close as your code but it is not preferable really:

```
from threading import Semaphore

def printTags(DevObj, s):
    ...
    s.release()
    ...

import threading, thread

# temp1 points to Block A.
# temp2 points to Block B.


s = Semaphore(0)
threads = [
    threading.Thread(target=printTags, args=(THING_TO_DO,s))
    for THING_TO_DO in THINGS_TO_DO
]
for t in threads:
    t.start()

while True:
    s.aquire()
    for t in threads:
        # give more work
```

More preferred option is to use producer/consumer pattern:

```
from threading import Semaphore

STOP = object()

def printTags(queue):
    while True:
        thing_to_process = queue.get()
        if thing_to_process is STOP:
            return
        else:
            #process 

import threading, thread

# temp1 points to Block A.
# temp2 points to Block B.

THREAD_COUNT = 2
s = Semaphore(0)
threads = [
    threading.Thread(target=printTags, args=(queue,))
    for _ in xrange(THREAD_COUNT)
]

for thing in things:
    queue.put(thing)
for _ in xrange(THREAD_COUNT):
    queue.put(STOP)

for t in threads:
    t.start()
```

Comment: Shouldn't you put one STOP per thread? If not, once you consume the STOP, shouldn't the other thread(s) lock?