# code not keep going after thread

Tags: python, windows, multithreading

I wrote this code to lock a mouse in the middle of the screen

```
def lockmouse():
print "here"
while True:
    win32api.SetCursorPos((GetSystemMetrics(0)/2,GetSystemMetrics(1)/2))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,GetSystemMetrics(0)/2,GetSystemMetrics(1)/2,0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,GetSystemMetrics(0)/2,GetSystemMetrics(1)/2,0,0)


t = threading.Thread(target=lockmouse())
command = "lockmouse"
    if "lockmouse" in command:
        if t.is_alive==False:
            t.start()
            time.sleep(3)
            t._Thread_stop()
```

and its not keep going after the t.start().I've been trying using different methods to stop the thread,but its even not make it after that line.anyone know what the problem?

Comment: It should be `target=lockmouse`. Don't call `lockmouse()`. It will never even execute `t.start()` because the current thread is in an infinite loop. The target function gets called in the new thread when you `start` it. Also, to exit the thread gracefully, the `while` loop should test a global variable or an object passed as a parameter, such as a `threading.Event`.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the fact that your function isn't indented properly. It should be:

```
def foo():
    return 'bar'
```

Also, you seem to only be starting a single thread. What's the point?

EDIT:

I just realised that your function has an infinite loop. The program cannot carry on from t.start() because it has to wait for that function to finish execution, which it won't because there's a while loop. You either need to restructure your program somehow, or if you want to keep it how it is, see this answer for how to avoid waiting for a thread.

[How to avoid waiting for a thread to finish execution - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510458/how-to-avoid-waiting-for-a-thread-to-finish-execution-python)